# Query timeout expired for a simple query

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-synapse

I'm using Azure Synapse Analytics and I'm trying to query the following

```
select count(*) from TABLE_1
inner join TABLE_2 on TABLE_1.KEY = TABLE_2.KEY
inner join TABLE_3 on TABLE_2.KEY = TABLE_3.KEY
inner join TABLE_4 on TABLE_3.KEY = TABLE_4.KEY
inner join TABLE_5 on TABLE_2.KEY = TABLE_5.KEY
```

but the output is: query timeout expired.

Three more facts:

1. If I query every single table (`select count(*) from TABLE_i`) then everything is ok;
2. If I query the first 4 tables, that is

   select count(*) from TABLE_1
   inner join TABLE_2 on TABLE_1.KEY = TABLE_2.KEY
   inner join TABLE_3 on TABLE_2.KEY = TABLE_3.KEY
   inner join TABLE_4 on TABLE_3.KEY = TABLE_4.KEY

then everything it's ok.

3. If I query only TABLE_2 joined with TABLE_5, everything it's ok in this case too.

   select count(*) from TABLE_2
   inner join TABLE_5 on TABLE_2.KEY = TABLE_5.KEY

Moreover the last join between TABLE_2 and TABLE_5 does **not** generates duplicates (so the total number of rows cannot grow).

Why the first join doesn't work? How can I resolve this?

Comment: Lack of indexing?

Comment: What are the counts for each of the tables individually?

Comment: In addition to rowcounts, what are the indexing choices (clustered columnstore index, heap, clustered index) and distribution choices (round robin, hash, replicate)?  What DWU is the database running at?  What is the resource class associated with the user running the query?  Is any other activity occurring causing the query to queue?  Remember concurrency is low for dedicated SQL pools especially at lower DWUs.  I would have thought hash distribution (on `key` column) would make sense for that query.

Comment: @NickW the counts range from 40k to 2 milions. Maybe the tables neither are so much big..

Comment: @wBob the TABLE_i are actually views. In the scripts of these views I can't see nothing about distribution or indexing choices. Do you think I can create another view from these with all the choices you mentioned? DWU: I don't know its value (I don't know where I can see it). Resource class: I query `SELECT name
FROM   sys.database_principals
WHERE  name LIKE '%rc%' AND type_desc = 'DATABASE_ROLE'` but I have no records. Finally, there's no other activity running.